# Simple get request won't work with AlamoFire

Tags: swift, swiftui, alamofire

I'm trying to do a simple get request with Alamofire but it isn't working.

SwiftUI:

```
struct Test: View {

   var body: some View {
       Button(action:{

        AF.request(“http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:3000/”, method: .get).responseString{ response in
            print(response)
        }        
    }){
        Text("Push Me")         
    }    
}
```

NodeJS:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   console.log(chalk.redBright("This route was hit"))
   res.send("Connected to server")      })
```

What can I do to make a simple get request with Alamofire? Strangely enough, I can upload images using AF without any problem.

***Edit:***
After playing around I found that it's a SwiftUI problem and not an Alamofire problem

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @BareMetal there unfortunately isn't an "err" or "error" in the callback. It's just "response"

Comment: Solved. There's nothing wrong with Alamofire, it's a SwiftUI issue